# Segmentation fault in UNIX but not Windows

Tags: c++, unix, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to get my DFS code working in UNIX, but whenever I run it it gives me a segmentation fault, yet it works fine in Windows. The code is supposed to take in a string and sort it to reach some predefined goal state by moving around a single letter at a time. I don't have much experience in UNIX so I would really appreciate some insight into this issue. Thank you!

```
struct node
{
    node* parent;
    string key;
    int cost;
    int heuristicCost;

    node()
    {
        parent = nullptr;
        key = "key";
        cost = 0;
        heuristicCost = 0;
    }
};

void BFS(string sortString)
{
    // Create Queue
    list<node*> queue;
    list<string> explored;
    // Add the initial case to the Queue
    node *n = new node;
    n->key = sortString;
    queue.push_back(n);
    int steps = 1;
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        // Print out the current node to be checked and the operation that was performed on it
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)queue.front()->key.length(); i++)
        {
            if (queue.front()->key[i] == 'X')
            {
                if (steps == 1)
                {
                    cout << queue.front()->key << endl;
                    steps++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout <<  "move " << i << " " << queue.front()->key << endl;
                    steps++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if the goal state is reached
        if (GoalTest(queue.front()->key))
        {
            cout << "Final Result for BFS:" << endl;
            node* currentNode = queue.front();
            list<node*> path;
            while (currentNode->parent != nullptr) {
                path.push_front(currentNode);
                currentNode = currentNode->parent;
            }
            int i = 1;
            while((int)path.size() >= 1)
            {
                cout << "Step " << i << ": " << path.front()->key << endl;
                i++;
                path.pop_front();
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // If goal state is not reached, add new nodes to the frontier
            explored.push_back(queue.front()->key);
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)queue.front()->key.length(); i++)
            {
                // Do a move action on the next node to be enqueued, if node is already in explored list, skip it
                string key = Move(i, queue.front()->key);
                bool found = (find(explored.begin(), explored.end(), key) != explored.end());
                if (found)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    node *newNode = new node;
                    newNode->key = key;
                    newNode->parent = queue.front();
                    queue.push_back(newNode);
                }
            }
            // Remove the first node of the queue
            queue.pop_front();
            bool found = (find(explored.begin(), explored.end(), queue.front()->key) != explored.end());
            while (found)
            {
                queue.pop_front();
                found = (find(explored.begin(), explored.end(), queue.front()->key) != explored.end());
            }
        }
    }
    // If loop exits normally, search failed
    cout << "Failure!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior tend to behave differently on different platforms and compilers. Since it crashes on one system, it makes sense to attempt to debug it on that platform, catching the crash *in action* so to say, to find out where it is and what might have caused it. Also using tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could be very helpful.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that a program with undefined behaviour can manifest different results on different platforms and compilers is exactly the point.

Comment: That last `pop_front()` and subsequent `front()` looks suspicious to me. How do you know there is another element to look at?

Comment: just a suggestion - don't use raw pointers.  It'll remove at least one path of UB without too much effort

Comment: What's the debugging process look like on UNIX? Whenever I run it there, it just gives me the segmentation fault and doesn't give me any other output at all, even if I add output specifically before I reach this function.
What would you suggest using instead of raw pointers?
What lines are you talking about when you say the last pop_front and subsequent front?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. "What's the debugging process look like on UNIX?" -- type this into your favorite search engine and read one of many fine tutorials on the subject. Here is one: https://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html